# Kivy RecycleView not showing data after moving into a screen

Tags: kivy

I've modified a Kivy RecycleView example and put it into a screen with menu, but now it's showing empty pages instead of data. I suspect the root have changed but I'm unable to connect the RecycleView to the correct source.

To be honest I think I've to work more on learning how to proper link between different objects.

My modified version that has the issue:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

KV = """

<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:

    ActionView:
        id: ActionView
        HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious:
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Stop'
            on_release:  app.stop()
       
       
<HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:

    
<MainBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            # source: 'data/background.png'

    MyManager:
        id: sm
        RVScreen:
            id: rvscreen

    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar


<RecycleItem>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.label_text
    TextInput:
        text: root.input_text
        on_text: root.set_text(self.text)

RecycleView:
    data: app.data
    viewclass: 'RecycleItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        default_size: None, dp(80)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height


<RVScreen>:
    id: "rvscreen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RecycleView:
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
"""

class RecycleItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    owner = ObjectProperty()
    index = NumericProperty(0)
    input_text = StringProperty()
    label_text = StringProperty()

    def set_text(self, text):
        if self.owner is not None:
            self.owner.data[self.index]['input_text'] = text
    
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(RecycleItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

class MainBox(BoxLayout):
    """Mainbox under MainApp
    It contains the ScreenManager
    """
    pass

class RVScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    """The screen manager that handles app screens
    """
    pass

class Test(App):
    data = ListProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.data = [{'label_text': "Label "+str(x), "input_text": "Input "+str(x), 'owner': self} for x in range(20)]
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        return MainBox()

Test().run()
```

Original working example:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV = """
<RecycleItem>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.label_text
    TextInput:
        text: root.input_text
        on_text: root.set_text(self.text)

RecycleView:
    data: app.data
    viewclass: 'RecycleItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        default_size: None, dp(80)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height


<RVScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RecycleView:
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
"""

class RecycleItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    owner = ObjectProperty()
    index = NumericProperty(0)
    input_text = StringProperty()
    label_text = StringProperty()

    def set_text(self, text):
        if self.owner is not None:
            self.owner.data[self.index]['input_text'] = text
    
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(RecycleItem, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

class Test(App):
    data = ListProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.data = [{'label_text': "Label "+str(x), "input_text": "Input "+str(x), 'owner': self} for x in range(20)]
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you want to put the `RecycleView` ?

Comment: I want to have in RVScreen. Just above the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `root` widget in several ways.

If you have the [`build`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) method in the `App`'s subclass and it returns some `Widget`, it will be set as the [`root`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.root) widget. Or you can assign the `root` to the kv-rule by loading it there etc.

In this case in your kv-rule you defined `RecycleView` as the `root` widget but you haven't used it in `build` to set it as the `root`.

Meanwhile you returned `MainBox` from the method `build` so it will be used as `root` widget. Again you loaded the kv-rule there so the design etc. will be applied to this root widget.

Now in order to add `RecycleView` to `RVScreen` (as you mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806213/kivy-recycleview-not-showing-data-after-moving-into-a-screen#comment126894272_71806213)) and set `MainBox` as `root` widget (as you did already) you can modify your `kvlang` as follows:

```py
<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:

    ActionView:
        id: ActionView
        HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious:
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Stop'
            on_release:  app.stop()
       
       
<HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:

    
<MainBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            # source: 'data/background.png'

    MyManager:
        id: sm
        RVScreen:
            id: rvscreen

    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar


<RecycleItem>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.label_text
    TextInput:
        text: root.input_text
        on_text: root.set_text(self.text)


<RVScreen>:
    id: "rvscreen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RecycleView:
            data: app.data
            viewclass: 'RecycleItem'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                spacing: 10
                default_size: None, dp(80)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
```

Comment: Also seems that `<RVScreen>:` in my original example was doing nothing. seems like I've modified the example in someway to add a screen, the original one didn't have such screen.